# The /reputation page is erroring on stackoverflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-page

Navigating to `stackoverflow/reputation` is resulting in:

> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred
>   while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded
>   and we have been notified.
>
> Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.
>
> It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional
>   information about this error, do so at our feedback site,
>   http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

For me at the moment. This is occuring when other activity on the site seems to be working ok for me, e.g. asking a question, so I'm fairly certain (unless they use different cookies) that I haven't got any mangled cookies, etc,..

Comment: Yep same here. Looks like one of those temporary global glitches (like the missing avatars saga) so I won't be too worried.

Comment: Oh I'm not worried, just rep-whoring ;) Joke! Whilst the development guys doubtless already know from their monitoring tools, mentioning it here at least lets other users know "It's not just you, it's at least one other person as well" =)

Comment: Well, that "eeek! my avatar is gone!" discussion was ultimately deleted so don't get your hopes too high for rep here. The dev guys don't like to keep record of shining errors like that. :/

Comment: By the way, it happens here in Meta as well.

Comment: Reputation is ephemeral in the grand scheme of things and once the issue is resolved this post will have approximately zero value to any future viewer of meta, so I wouldn't be surprised if it's deleted in the least =)

Comment: we are looking into this, will sort it out

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd "The dev guys don't like to keep record of shining errors like that." Yeah, because all fixed bug reports here on meta are deleted :\ I'll assume you're joking, otherwise that's just trolling.

Comment: @balpha maybe I was sarcastic, sorry for that. My point was exactly what you said: that bug reports won't stay for long - thanks for fixing this one. By the way, is it related to the [suggested edit bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121057)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue was resolved by the judicious application of waffles. After all, what isn't made better by waffles? =)