# Has the editing "peer revised" policy changed?

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, suggested-edits, privileges

I was going to edit a post today and I found that the option `edit` doesn't appear anymore. I can only see `flag` and `link`. That is happening with **all posts** in SO and Meta.

It looks like people with less than 2000 reputation cannot see the `edit` link anymore, so it looks that now it is not possible to edit even peer revised unless you have 2000 reputation.

Does anybody know more details?

Comment: Maybe because of this?: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84671/missing-edit-link

Comment: No, that's not the reason. On SO there is now exactly zero suggested edits in the review queue. That's really unusual!

Comment: hm right I cannot see it here with my meta user, but can see it on so with my 2k+ user

Comment: I see the edit link on Pro Webmasters (914 rep) but not Photography (322 rep).

Comment: Can't see edit links in [gaming.se] & [dba.se] - as an anon I can't see the "Improve this post" option either

Comment: I retagged to bug as I can't imagine that being intentional.

Comment: Correction - I'm only seeing the "retag" link on Pro Webmasters and Server Fault (914 and 1519 rep respectively) the question I checked on Pro Webmasters was Community Wiki!

Comment: FWIW, I just saw [a suggested edit for a tag](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/193185) in the queue, so it *seems* to only affect questions & answers.

Comment: As a side-note: Please stop all those really minor spelling correction edits.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: They're not "really minor". Posts without capitalisation are highly irritating.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Jav's edits seem to have gotten a bit more substantial. Editing a post replacing only `i` by `I` and leaving other issues such as greetings is a bit annoying.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I went back to Feb 2. He should have taken out the greetings at the same time but may not have realised that it ought to be done. Correcting "i" to "I" is desirable and I thank him for doing so.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Fix is being rolled out as we speak. A recent change with regard to suggested edit permissions had an "or" where there should have been an "and". Turns out that this changes the meaning.

Comment: Nice reading this. xD

Comment: I take all the blame for that ...

Comment: Oh, you mean `or` and `and` aren't exact equivalents? Hmm... this could explain a lot! hehe (Of course, I've *never* made such a mistake. Ever. Never... nope...)

Comment: _execute! no mercy_ instead of _execute no! mercy_

Answer (score 8):

<strike>It means someone was faster than you and already suggested edit of his/her own.</strike>

When there is already suggested edit in the queue (waiting to be approved or rejected) no further edits can be suggested.

Give link to the question you tried to edit and we can confirm this. :)

According to the new information provided and considering there was no suggested edit [for **over 2 hours**](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/suggested-edits) (10K+ page showing list of suggested edits during the day) I would say you stumbled upon a major bug.. it's surely no policy change, just a bug.

From quick check looks like it's all across the network, maybe related to [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121051/the-reputation-page-is-erroring-on-stackoverflow) as well - I'm sure the developers are aware of this and working to solve this as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Check some other posts if you can see the edit link there, the usual reason you don't see one is that there is already a suggested edit in the queue. If there is already a suggested edit on a post, sub-2k users don't see the edit link.

As you don't see the edit link anywhere, I checked on another site myself and also don't see it. I expect that this is a bug, as I can't imagine they removed suggested edits for registered users.

Comment: I cannot see the edit link in any post.